# Laravel submit button does nothing when clicked

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I made an update form in Laravel, but every time I click the submit button, nothing happens and also no errors are showing. I tried changing the route post URL and still, nothing happens.

Here are the routes that I used:

```
Route::get('/edit_product/{id}','UpdateController@editProduct');
Route::post('/edit_product/{id}','UpdateController@saveEdit');
```

My controller code:

```
public function editProduct($id){
    $products = Products::find($id);
    return view('products.update', ['products'=>$products]);
}

public function saveEdit(Request $request, $id){
    $products = Products::find($id);

    $products->product_name = $request->get('product_name');
    $products->price = $request->get('price');
    $products->category = $request->get('category');
    $products->subcategory = $request->get('subcategory');
    $products->details = $request->get('details');
    $products->save();
    return redirect('products');    
}
```

And in my blade file, I used this:

```
<form method = "POST" action = '{{ url("/edit_product/{id}")}}' enctype = "multipart/form-data">
```

Here is my submit button:

```
<input type = "submit" name = "sub" value = "Done">
```

Comment: check by inspecting the page... what url is coming in form action attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is a good practice to name your route / url and secondly, it is the issue with url in action attribute, it is not created properly.

You need to do the following:

Name your route using `name()` method:

```
Route::post('/edit_product/{id}','UpdateController@saveEdit')->name('edit_product');
```

Use the name to create url with id of product as the parameter using `route()` method:

```
<form method = "POST" action = "{{ route('edit_product', ['id' => $product->id]) }}" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
```

**TIP**: it is better to use `$product` as variable name rather than `$products` as `find()` method returns a single model object or `null`.

Answer (score -3):

First check if it saves the changes to the database.
Secondly check if it logs any error.